# Jekyll rendering inner element outside parent tag

Tags: sass, jekyll, liquid

I'm creating a site using the Hydejack Jekyll template.

The following HTML snippet:

```
<p class="note">
      <ul>
        <li>Programming Concepts</li>
        <li>Program Analysis</li>
        <li>Data Structures & Algorithms</li>
        <li>Databases</li>
        <li>Fundamentals of Machine Learning</li>
        <li>Natural Language Engineering</li>
      </ul>
</p>
```

and relevant SCSS:

```
.note-sm {
  @extend .message;
  background: transparent;
  color: var(--body-color);
  font-size: smaller;
  border-left: 1px solid var(--border-color);
  padding: 1.2rem 1rem 0 1rem;
  margin: 1rem -1rem;
  position: relative;

  &:before {
    font-size: 0.667rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
    letter-spacing: .025rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: var(--menu-text);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
  }

  &[title]:before {
    content: attr(title)!important;
  }
}

.note {
  @extend .note-sm;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

Renders as so: [Outside tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPtgQ.png)

The ul element is outside the p element. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/grouping-content.html#the-p-element), there are certain tags that imply the close of a `p` tag:

> A p element's end tag can be omitted if the p element is immediately followed by an address, article, aside, blockquote, details, div, dl, fieldset, figcaption, figure, footer, form, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, header, hgroup, hr, main, menu, nav, ol, p, pre, section, table, or **ul** element, or if there is no more content in the parent element and the parent element is an HTML element that is not an a, audio, del, ins, map, noscript, or video element, or an autonomous custom element.

So you'll have to use another containing tag (i.e. `div`), or deal with the `ul` as a sibling of the `p`.